# Change position of divs outside container to hover below divs in container

Tags: html, css, position

The structure and everything is here:

```css
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.map{
  position: relative;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background-color: orange;
  z-index: -1;
}

.marker {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 3;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.marker :hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.description {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  width: 150px;
  height:150px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="map">
        <div class="marker"></div>        
      </div>
      <div class="description"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And link to plunkr:
https://next.plnkr.co/edit/cfBk4SPfuPZIaJFK

Description needs to be outside map div, and I'd like to make description go under the marker, but I can't get it done with position absolute and z-indexes. Any ideas?

Comment: remove z-index from map and it's should be good

Comment: Thanks for answer! It's working now, but how to reset z-index to none if it was previously set by different style.css? I'm importing google maps and it's position and z-index is pre set with it's styles? Any idea?

Comment: make it `z-index:auto`